# Why is the car crash not inverted in the inverted world?

Tags: tenet

Here the Inverted Protagonist is stuck inside a car, which is damaged by a car crash.

[image: animated GIF of the described scene]

It's the inverted world, so a car crash should be like inverted, but this one looks normal.

Why is the car crash not inverted in the inverted world?

Comment: Earlier we saw the same car crash from the normal forward-time perspective, and from that perspective the crash looked inverted--the car was first seen lying on the road, then it started bouncing backwards, its dents and broken windows healing, until it righted itself and started driving backwards. This car was one the Protagonist found parked outside the facility where Sator had the large Turnstile (big enough to fit a car), so although it wasn't stated explicitly, I think the implication was that it was an inverted car that was parked there in case any inverted people needed to use it.

Comment: Does that mean the combustion engine of the other cars fills the gas tank with CO_2 pull in via the exhaust?

Comment: @Hypnosifl you should write that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

The car (the Saab) is inverted and the scene is shown from the inverted point of view. Hence, the car crash looks normal. The Tallinn turnstile is large enough to fit a car.

> The mystery is solved, at least as far as the Saab is concerned.
> There's a car in the red (non-inverted) side of the turnstile facility
> at the end of the car chase. We never get a good look at it, but it
> has the right shape and the right hub-caps to be the same Saab that we
> see in the car chase sequence. (At around the time of this shot, the
> inverted version of the same car is currently pulling up outside.)
>
> [image]
>
> Here's a shot of the Saab for comparison:
>
> [image]
>
> I [realised](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/112527/1006) that the
> Tenet paramilitaries don't hold the facility after they capture it -
> they all invert at the same time as the protagonist, leaving it empty.
> So we can assume that after that, Sator's people will turn up, take
> the algorithm from the inverted Saab, and then invert this car (which
> of course becomes the inverted one), thus ensuring that the events
> will play out as they did and they will end up with the algorithm.

Source: (Movies & TV SE) [How did the cars get inverted in Tenet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/112326/1006)